# What is the meaning of "I could really use a break from this place"?

Tags: phrases

I ask this because I am unable to understand the uses of *could* and *can* ?

Comment: I'm confused by what you are asking.  Your question in the title and your question in the body seem to be asking for two different things.  First, you ask for a definition of an idiomatic phrase, and second, you ask for a distinction between "could" and "can".  You've also showed no attempt to research any solution.  A quick Google search for "could can" reveals a number of sources discussing this distinction.

Answer (score 2):

The word *could* in your sentence expresses a hypothetical, yet-to-be state of mind. In effect, the sentence means:

> "Given the opportunity, I would really appreciate getting away from here. I need a break, a time to relax and recharge my batteries."

Another way of expressing the same thought:

> "If given the opportunity, I would really appreciate being given a break from this place."

Again, the person expresses the notion of something which has yet to happen, and does so with a bit more emphasis than if he had used the word *could*. Chances are, the speaker would emphasize the word *really*. Notice, too, that the extra word *appreciate* adds a new wrinkle to the sentence, and in effect creates more emphasis. In other words, the speaker has not yet been given a break, but *given the chance*, he would certainly appreciate being given a break. Perhaps he is extremely tired.

The word *can* denotes the physical ability to do something. In grade school, when a 7-year old child asks the teacher,

> "Can I go to the bathroom?"

the teacher might say,

> "Well, I certainly hope you can!"

That is the teacher's way of correcting the child's grammar, since the correct way of expressing that question is:

> "May I go to the bathroom?"

Keeping in mind that *can* expresses physical ability, which of the following sentences is correct?

1. I can use a glass of water. [said by someone who is thirsty]
2. I can balance a glass of water on my forehead.

If you said "two," you'd be correct. To correct the first sentence, simply replace *can* with *could*, and the person is in effect saying

> If I were to be given a glass of water, I would surely accept it, because boy, am I thirsty!

In conclusion, *can* expresses the ability to do something in the present, but *could* expresses a real or hypothetical desire to do something in the future.

> - I could balance a glass of water on my head, if I wanted to.
> - I can balance a glass of water on my head, and I'll show you I can do it right now!

Answer (score 1):

Could implies that something **might be** possible or the speaker wishes it might be possible.
Can means that something **is** possible.
For example you might say "I could buy a car if I had the money" - the money condition needs to be true to make the buying possible.
If you say "I can buy a car" then you imply that you have enough money.